# How to run a powershell script that is based online

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a Powershell script that is stored here:

https://gitlab.example.example.co.uk/example/example/raw/master/shrink-diskpart.ps1

I would like to run this on many servers through a scheduled task from this gitlab so I can make single changes to the script and it will run the most up to date one on all the servers.

Can anyone advise if this is possible an if it is how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Invoke-WebRequest with -OutFile to download a file, and then just execute it.  You might store the file on the web server as a .txt so that you don't have to add a MIME type.

```
$scriptUrl = "http://localhost/test.txt"
$destination = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$scriptName = "c:\temp\test.ps1"

Invoke-WebRequest $scriptUrl -OutFile $destination

# if the file was downloaded, delete the old script file and rename the new
# file
if(test-path $destination){
    remove-item $scriptName
    Rename-Item $destination $scriptName
}

&$scriptName
```

Props to http://www.powershellatoms.com/basic/download-file-website-powershell/